# Did anyone experience also malfunctions at their action since the Google Update a few weeks ago?

Tags: console, updates, actions-on-google, assistant

The actions worked properly before Google changed the UI and probably some more things at the assistant console. Now the action some times works and some times does not work.

Error messages at the simulator ar for instance:

1. We're sorry, but something went wrong. Please try again.
2. No output at all (with intent next / previous)
3. Sorry, this action is not available in simulation

Comment: Hello. Are you still receiving this issue? Can you provide a more detailed log and specify if you are using Dialogflow or Actions Builder for building your conversational Action?

Comment: Hello. We are using Dialogflow.